# Are maps and operators between two sets the same?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I have been reading on up on the definition of maps and operators, specifically reacting to sets (rather then the more restricted vector spaces) and their definitions seem to be identical. So are all maps between the set A and B operators and vice versa i.e. is the term operator simply a synonym for the word map?

Comment: Operator, function, transformation, map, application, ... What else? Assignation!? All the same.